# How do I generate decryption keys for the IDEA algorithm from the 128 bit key?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, key

I am trying to implement IDEA algorithm in C#, just to learn how it works. I have taken a 128 bit binary key and generated the 52 encryption keys using the following code:

```
static ushort[] getKeys(string binaryKey)
{
        ushort[] keys = new ushort[52];
        int index = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            int bitPos = 0;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            if (index == 52)
                break;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            keys[index++] = Convert.ToUInt16(binaryKey.Substring(bitPos, 16), 2);
            bitPos += 16;
            binaryKey = binaryKey.Substring(25) + binaryKey.Substring(0, 25);
        }
        return keys;
}
```

This function, I believe, returns the right values (I couldn't test them, but they're in the bounds). And now, I am unable to  understand how to get those decryption keys. I also couldn't find enough text on the matter.

**EDIT**:
This is the method I used to generate the Decryption Keys -

```
static ushort[] generateDecryptionKeys(ushort[] encKeys)
{
        ushort[] decKeys = new ushort[52];

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; )
        {
            decKeys[i++] = (ushort)GetModMulInv(encKeys[52 - i], 65537);
            decKeys[i++] = (ushort)AdditiveInv(encKeys[52 - i]);
            decKeys[i++] = (ushort)AdditiveInv(encKeys[52 - i]);
            decKeys[i++] = (ushort)GetModMulInv(encKeys[52 - i], 65537);
            if (i == 52) break;
            decKeys[i++] = encKeys[52 - i];
            decKeys[i++] = encKeys[52 - i];
        }

        return decKeys;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'And now, I am unable to understand how to get those decryption keys'?

Comment: Well, I just meant 'after doing it right so far', I am unable to forward.

Comment: By 'get those decryption keys' I mean 'generate the decryption keys'.

Answer (score 0):

The decryption key schedule, uses the same 52 keys in reverse order.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work if you mean to use the same encryption function for decryption with the sequence of keys reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use keys in the following order:

```
Encryption: K1       K2  K3     K4      K5  k6  (round 1)
Decryption: k49^-1   -k50 -k51  k49^-1  k47 k48 (round 2)
```

I assumed you have done modulo multiplication using `k1` and `k4` with your input data block and modulo addition for `k2` and `k3`.